# ESLint Async pipes should not be negated

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I'm using ESLint with Angular and I don't like having extra code like `(observable | async) === (false | null | undefined)` instead of just `(observable | async)`. How do I disable that rule?

```
E:\GitHub\skybot\angular\src\app\custom-layout\custom-layout.component.html
  6:75  error  Async pipes should not be negated. Use (observable | async) === (false | null | undefined) to check its value instead  @angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async
```

### custom-layout.component.html

```
<ng-template #sidenavRef>
  <vex-sidenav [collapsed]="sidenavCollapsed$ | async"></vex-sidenav>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #toolbarRef>
  <vex-toolbar [hasShadow]="toolbarShadowEnabled$ | async" [mobileQuery]="!(isDesktop$ | async)" class="vex-toolbar">
  </vex-toolbar>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #footerRef>
  <vex-footer *ngIf="isFooterVisible$ | async" class="vex-footer"></vex-footer>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #quickPanelRef>
  <vex-quick-panel></vex-quick-panel>
</ng-template>

<vex-layout [footerRef]="footerRef" [quickPanelRef]="quickPanelRef" [sidenavRef]="sidenavRef" [toolbarRef]="toolbarRef">
</vex-layout>

<vex-config-panel-toggle (openConfig)="configPanel.open()"></vex-config-panel-toggle>

<!-- CONFIGPANEL -->
<vex-sidebar #configPanel [invisibleBackdrop]="true" position="right">
  <vex-config-panel></vex-config-panel>
</vex-sidebar>
<!-- END CONFIGPANEL -->
```

### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "vex",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "vex",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "arrow-parens": [
          "off",
          "always"
        ],
        "id-blacklist": "error",
        "import/order": "off",
        "max-len": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We can see from the ESLint config that you have examples of rules being disabled, and the name of the rule you want to disable is in the error, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I don't get it. What exactly line do you refer to from the config?

Comment: Have a look at https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, `"@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off",` did nothing

Comment: That seems unlikely, but it's not clear where you've put it. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated the question

Comment: You've put it in the `"rules"` for `"*.ts"` files, but you're showing an error in a `"*.html"` file.

Comment: @johnrsharpe,  thank you! You were right, it worked

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think this is a very good rule and we must follow that.

Why?

> Angular’s async pipes emit null initially, prior to the observable
> emitting any values, or the promise resolving. This can cause
> negations, like *ngIf=”!(myConditional | async)” to thrash the layout
> and cause expensive side-effects like firing off XHR requests for a
> component which should not be shown.

**Doc:** http://codelyzer.com/rules/templates-no-negated-async/

So you can just use like so according to your use case. i.e. for me it is just a `boolean` check.

`(isMemberChanged$ | async) !== true`

Comment: How is !null different than null !== true ?

Comment: @AaronUllal I have mentioned it for a `boolean` value. i.e. not for a `null`.

Comment: Another solution would be to create a `| isTruthy` pipe that coerces values to truthy/falsy.

Answer (score 7):

add `"@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off"` to the html portion of the esLint rules section

Answer (score 4):

edit **.eslintrc.json** in root or your project (5 row from end), possible variants: off/warn/error

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "crm",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "crm",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need the negated async to deal with all falsies. For example with loaders observables.

So if you want to disable this rule you should edit the html rules in the .eslintrc.json

```
{
  ...
  "overrrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
         "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": "off"
      }
  ]
}
```