# *ngIf with a NOT (!) with async pipe for BehaviorSubject or Promise throws condition error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if, behaviorsubject

`*ngIf` for async NOT condition?

So I have a fairly simple login service that uses the behavior subject library to know when a user is logged in.

`login.service.ts`:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    this.loggedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}

getLoginStatus(){
    return this.loggedSubject.asObservable();
}
```

And a login component, in which I want to make the register button NOT show if the user is logged in.

So I did followings in `login.component.html`:

```
<button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/register"  (click)="sidenav.toggle()" *ngIf="!getLoginStatus() | async">
      <mat-icon>key</mat-icon>
      <span>Register</span>
```

where I've got:

```
ERROR

src/app/header/header.component.html:33:102 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Observable<unknown> | Subscribable<unknown> | Promise<unknown>): unknown', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<unknown> | Subscribable<unknown> | Promise<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(obj: null | undefined): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(obj: Observable<unknown> | Subscribable<unknown> | Promise<unknown> | null | undefined): unknown', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<unknown> | Subscribable<unknown> | Promise<unknown> | null | undefined'.

33     <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/register"  (click)="sidenav.toggle()" *ngIf="!getLoginStatus() | async">
                                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/header/header.component.ts:21:16
    21   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
```

The above works perfectly without the "!" (not) operator. Also from what I've seen there's not `ngNotIf`, how can I bypass this problem?

Thanks to everyone for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*ngIf="!(getLoginStatus() | async)"
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwl3qt?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Jesus, I'm sure I tried this syntax, but I was prolly mistyping something. Thanks, mate.

Comment: I have added a demo

Answer (score 1):

```
*ngIf="!(getLoginStatus() | async)"
```

caused ESLint to throw:

```
Async pipe results should not be negated.
Use `(observable | async) === false`, `(observable | async) === null`, or `(observable | async) === undefined` to check its value instead
eslint@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async
```

Per [ESLint documentation](http://codelyzer.com/rules/templates-no-negated-async/) and [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971535/1964319), the following is better:

```
*ngIf="(getLoginStatus() | async) !== true"
```

Answer (score 0):

We are getting error on using ! (not operator) because we have used **async** pipe for either observables or promises. so what happened actually there  the value does not get resolved or subscribed because its value is resolved or subscribed by **async** pipe so  use:

```
*ngIf="!(getLoginStatus() | async)"
```

we just first resolved or subscribed the value (by putting in small brackets) then after getting value we attach the **not (!)** operator.

**Brackets are the part of priority.**